# Gitlab pre-receive hook

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

I want to make a pre-receive hook (it should work from the side of Gitlab), that does the following:

- When somebody pushes to gitlab, it looks through files for ones with extensions .py.
- Files with extension .py should be run through pylint
- If they have any errors, the push should be rejected.

The main problem: as I know git works with changes. All the files that I'll get will have only some lines of code that are added or deleted. As a result I can't test them by pylint.

What I want to do: I want to make a temporary push of all files. Looking through last commits, I'll find files with .py and check them by pylint. In case of errors I will reject the push.

The question: Looking through different tutorials, I haven't found the way to do it. Do you have any ideas how to do it? Or maybe some better implementations for this task?

Comment: Indeed git hooks receive old and new states. But who prevents you from getting diff for a given pair of states, selecting only .py files if any, then extracting (e.g. with `git-show`) required files and finally running a lintian on them?

Answer (score -2):

Have you read through this page https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy? You can use that to get the updated refs on the server side, check for updated .py files, and pylint them, and reject ones failing pylint.

Comment: Looks like a decent comment, not an answer :)

Comment: Its about as much time as I would want to allocate for a 1 dot 2 ranked user.

Comment: No, I don't mind, but the place for this phrase is in the comments section, formally.